# G torsor v.s. Principal G-bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

> G torsor v.s. Principal G-bundle

Are [G torsors always Principal G-bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsor_(algebraic_geometry))?

How are G torsors related to Principal G-bundles?

- Is that G torsor primarily for algebraic geometry?
- While Principal G-bundle is primarily for differential geometry or algebraic topology?

Comment: The fibers of a principal $G$-bundle are $G$-torsors. In a sense, every $G$-torsor is a principal $G$-bundle over the singleton.

Comment: As Kakelad said a $G$-torsor is the same thing as a principal $G$-bundle over a singleton hence not a very deep notion. Well, in fact in may well become one : replace singleton by terminal object (the same thing right ?). Now in algebraic geometry (as opposed to differential geometry), the terminal object is not so simple and in fact can be anything if we are talking about $S$-schemes. So : a principal $G$-bundle over $S$ is the same thing as a $G$-torsor in the category of spaces over $S$

Comment: many thanks!!! <3